# Redirect URL in CCAvenue

Tags: payment-gateway, prestashop, ccavenue

i am setting up CCAvenue for my prestashop site.After successful credit card transaction, when coming back to website, shopping cart items are not clearing and also orders are not updating.I think the problem is with the return URL in merchant account settings. What should be the return URL in ccavenue settings page? 
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After regenerating key my problem has been solved. And the return Page URL is `http://myshop/modules/ccavenue/validation.php`.

Comment: it redirects to url you supplied while calling ccavenue page or the url which you setup in ccavenue administrator page?

Comment: How can we read  response from custom url . I mean payment status and receipt id etc